# Convert IF to more OOP approach in method

Tags: php, oop

Cannot think of any way to convert this IF's used to see number of params for `bindParam()` into some something more in OOP friendly.
Can something other than using `switch` statement be done here? 
Is it good OOP practice to have his IFs in method anyway?

Ad-Hoc Polymorphism perhaps?

```
class MySQL_Query {

    protected $dbh;

    public function __construct($dbh) {
        $this->dbh = $dbh;
    }

    public function SelectQuery($query, $param) {

        $PDOStatement = $this->$dbh->PDO->prepare($query);

        if (isset($param[3])) {
            $PDOStatement->bindParam($param[0], $param[1], $param[2], $param[3]);
        } elseif (isset($param[2])) { 
            $PDOStatement->bindParam($param[0], $param[1], $param[2]);
        } else {
            $PDOStatement->bindParam($param[0], $param[1]);
        }

        $PDOStatement->execute();

        $result = array();

        while ( $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NAMED) ) {
            $result[] = $row;
        }

        return $result;

    }

}
```

**EDIT** My Solution here is what i was asking for how to remove `IF`, as i dont' want to pass params to `execute()` directly because they treated as `PDO::PARAM_STR` and you cannot change that. Here is how i eliminated ugly `IF` i translated it to `ternary IF`, looks way more readable now and shorter.

```
$PDOStatement->bindParam(   $param[0], //parameter
                            $param[1], //variable with value
                            !empty($param[2]) ? $param[2] : null, //data_type
                            !empty($param[3]) ? $param[3] : null, //length
                            !empty($param[4]) ? $param[5] : null  //driver_options
                         );
```

Comment: Couldn't you just pass `$param` to the `$PDOStatement->execute($param);` statement?

Comment: What happens if someone wants to use 4 parameters? Pass the parameters as an array, and pass it directly, or run it through a loop. (No need, you can pass the array directly to the `execute()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) accepts an array of parameters

unnamed parameters

```
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of insert values */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->execute(array($calories, $colour));
```

named parameters

```
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of insert values */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => $calories, ':colour' => $colour));
```

variable number of parameters using `IN` query

```
/* Execute a prepared statement using an array of values for an IN clause */
$params = array(1, 21, 63, 171);
/* Create a string for the parameter placeholders filled to the number of params */
$place_holders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($params), '?'));

/*
    This prepares the statement with enough unnamed placeholders for every value
    in our $params array. The values of the $params array are then bound to the
    placeholders in the prepared statement when the statement is executed.
    This is not the same thing as using PDOStatement::bindParam() since this
    requires a reference to the variable. PDOStatement::execute() only binds
    by value instead.
*/
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM contacts WHERE id IN ($place_holders)");
$sth->execute($params);
```

<sub>source: [PDOStatement::execute docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)</sub>

Comment: @Darren yeah, that's a particularly tricky query – especially for how commonly people need it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer however i don't like that when i pass parameters directly to PDO::execute() it treats all parameters as PDO::PARAM_STR by default  i'd like to specify correct data type and length when defining parameters it makes it easier to read the code for me.